# Finding minimum value of a sum

Tags: inequality, optimization, summation

Consider the sum $S=a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n=1120$ and the expression $$\frac{1}{2}\left(a_1(a_1-1)+a_2(a_2-1)+\ldots+a_n(a_n-1)\right).$$ Is it possible to obtain a nice non-trivial lower bound for such sum?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your sum is equal to $\frac12(a_1^2 + \cdots + a_n^2) - 560$, from expanding the brackets, collecting the first-degree terms and using the assumption. Next, the AM-QM inequality tells us that
$$
\sqrt{\frac{a_1^2 + \cdots + a_n^2}{n}}\geq \frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n}\\
a_1^2 + \cdots + a_n^2 \geq\frac{\left(1120\right)^2}{n} = \frac{1\,254\,400}{n}
$$
with equality iff $a_1 = a_2 = \cdots = a_n$. Thus we get
$$
\frac12(a_1^2 + \cdots + a_n^2) - 560 \geq \frac{627\,200}{n} - 560
$$
still with equality iff all the $a_i$ are equal.